# Is there any other way to build opencv for visual studio 2015?

Tags: c#

I have tried [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/opencv/blob/vs2015-samples/README.md) GitHub repository and followed the instructions, but it has setup to build opencv for VS2012,13 only and fails and I am new to .net environment so it's a bit complicated. I just want to know whether their is some other way?

If you downvote my question please tell the reason fo doing so as I am new to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long way mentioned in your link should work. Any how, I built opencv for VS2015 a few days back using CMAKE-GUI tool. It's pretty easy to use. Just enter the link of the source folder in the source directory and make a new folder where you want to build opencv and enter that path in build directory.

You will get some errors but you can ignore them. This is the detailed [link](http://funvision.blogspot.in/2015/11/install-opencv-visual-studio-2015.html).